# Login other users via script

Tags: macos, mac, user-accounts

We've been using our Mac mini's for our Xamarin builds for a while now, but it's always a very tedious process to setup these builds.

The main problem we're having is that our users needs to be logged in in order for our buildserver to connect. For each customer we have an user account so that our Provisioning profiles are separated.

If we reboot the computer this means we have to manually login 20 user accounts. I am wondering if this process can be done automatically. I know there are command's like: su - username, but this requires me to enter the password on the next line. Is there a oneliner for logging in users with password?

I hope someone is able to help me out! Thanks in advance